# process Dialog not Showing immediately in List View

Tags: android

Hi I am new in android and I am trying to put process Dialog on click event of list view, No doubt its working but I found that process Dialog shows very late, I need that, It should be show immediately after I click,  my peace of code is here. please give me appropriate solution for this.  Thanks !

```
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,
                final int position, long id) {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(v.getRootView().getContext(), "",
                    "Please Wait....", true, true);
            MyThreadNew myThread = new MyThreadNew(position);
        //  myThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            myThread.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you testing it in Emulator then it will be slow in reponse, so just check on device

Comment: ok, I tested in device also,same problem and another things I can't recognize your comment

Comment: pd = ProgressDialog.show(yourActivity.this, "",
                    "Please Wait....", true, true);
try this